# DateTime Conversion Error when I tried to convert PDT time

Tags: c#

When I tried to convert PDT time to `en-US` culture it is not working.

```
 DateTime.Parse("Wed, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14 PDT",new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

But this is working

```
 DateTime.Parse("Wed, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14",new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: It is because the zone abbreviations are not recognised by `Parse`, you would have to either remove them or convert them to relevant offsets (gotta use `ParseExact`)

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to parse `DateTime` from that string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use time-zones in `DateTime.Parse()`, but you can handle them separately.

Try this:

```
var time =  DateTime.Parse("Fri, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14",new CultureInfo("en-US"));
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var pdtTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(time, zone);
```

**Update 1:** Oops, got this the wrong way around. Here is the (correct) counterpart:

```
var enUsTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(pdtTime, zone);
```

*Oh, and by the way - your original example will not work because `08 Jun 2012` is not a `Wed`, but rather a `Fri`... ;)*

**Update 2:**

If all you need is a TimeDate, then you can parse is as follows (lin

```
using System.Linq; // Include a ref to LINQ

(...)

var originalDate = "Fri, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14 PDT";
// Use LINQ to fetch the first 25 characters (ignoring "PDT"):
var dateToParse = new string(originalDate.Take(25).ToArray());
var result = DateTime.Parse(dateToParse, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: thanks, what i asked is to convert `Wed, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14 PDT` to `en-US` Culture. But in your `DateTime.Parse` you missed `PDT`

Comment: also can you check your code, `utcNow`?

Comment: I asked for converting from `PDT` to `en-US` but your code is reversed

Comment: Thanks, I will be having only this DateTime String `Fri, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14 PDT` but not `Fri, 08 Jun 2012 12:14:14`. Can you check your first line of code?

Comment: Ok, I suppose I misunderstood. What do you expect as a result though? If all you want is a `DateTime` with the original date, then can't you just parse the substring, as you did in your second line of code in the original post?

Comment: I just want output as DateTime. Do i need to replace PDT to "" from DateTime String and then do casting?

Comment: @sss No problem. Added a couple of lines more; what I think might be the easiest/shortest way to parse it. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks that works, i accept your answer